# php encoding utf-8 displayed as ansi

Tags: php, apache, utf-8, character-encoding, fcgid

I know this is at age old question but here it goes again.

But i do have really strange issue.

php file containing this
encodingtest.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php 
echo 'テキスト'
?>
```

prints out

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
????
</body>
</html>
```

very very strange issue

even with php file containing with just this line

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

produces this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=
"text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am lost on what to do.
anyone can help point out what I need to do. Would really be helpful
the output of phpinfo() is in this link http://pastebin.com/zgKaRHxa
any help is really appreciated..
thanks in advance

EDIT:
meta tag was not visible so used code function to make it visble

Comment: Did you save php file in UTF8 encoding?

Comment: yes it tried with both UTF8 and ascii encoding both produces junk characters..

Comment: just an udpate ..fixed the issue it was php error.. its possible update broke it.. i havent tried to figure out exact cause though.. cause i am more into java than php..